# Rank keys of dict with lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary referring to a set of documents. Each document is associated with the frequencies of 5 specific words, which I captured in a list for each value in the dict. The dict looks something like this:

```
docs = {'doc1': [144, 91, 1, 28, 130], 'doc2': [3, 4, 21, 59, 319], 'doc3': [4, 121, 12, 14, 23]}
```

Now, I'm looking to rank the keys in this dict based on these word frequencies. Specifically, I want to rank them five times (for each of the five values). So doc1 comes out on top in ranking 1, doc3 comes out on top in ranking 2, etc.

I then want to produce a final ranking of the docs, which takes the average rank per doc and then ranks the averages.

I'm new to Python and getting a bit lost in sorted dicts, addressing lists in dicts, etc. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you `produce a final ranking based on the average of the five rankings.` ? Can you explain the algorithm a bit?

Comment: Apologies, that last part was unclear. I want to produce overall ranks signalling the importance of each doc in the list across the 5 intermediate rankings. I'd like to take the average rank per doc and then rank the averages.

Answer (score 1):

First, make the full list of names:

```
names = list(docs.keys()) # list() not needed in Python 2
```

Then, [sort it using custom criteria](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

```
sorted(names, key=lambda name: docs[name][0], reverse=True)
```

Or for all 5 at once:

```
[sorted(names, key=lambda name: docs[name][ii], reverse=True) for ii in range(5)]
```

Which gives you:

```
[['doc1', 'doc3', 'doc2'],
 ['doc3', 'doc1', 'doc2'],
 ['doc2', 'doc3', 'doc1'],
 ['doc2', 'doc1', 'doc3'],
 ['doc2', 'doc1', 'doc3']]
```

As for the overall ranking, you could rank them by total counts like this:

```
sorted(names, key=lambda name: sum(docs[name]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: That's missing the last step: the final ranking based on the average ranking.

Comment: @MSeifert: I've added the final step now.

Comment: I think it's still not correct because it reads as if it should be based on the **intermediate rankings** not the average (or sum) of the values. But I may be wrong :)

Comment: I think, OP can't quite clarify the second requirement. I have already asked for it, let's see how OP explains it. Till now it's quite a nice solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd never used custom sorting before. The last part wasn't quite clear--I edited the question. I would like to create an average rank per doc and then rank the averages.

Comment: @Tom: I invite you to go ahead and try to realize your final goal in code.  I'm not planning to write it for you.

Comment: Of course, already working on it. It was just to clarify the question. Thanks again.